# How to reload secrets.yml without restart rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How to reload secrets.yml without restart rails server, like if I manually update secrets.yml credentials on updating it will auto load to the rails application

eg in secrets.yml

```
   api_key: 1111111111
```

In the application, I can access using

```
   puts Rails.application.secrets.api_key
   => '1111111111'
```

for example, if I manually update secrets.yml file

```
   api_key: 222222222
```

In the application, the result should have to be this

```
   puts Rails.application.secrets.api_key
   => '222222222'
```

Without restarting server